# What kind of thread-safety is needed when using cuCtxSetCurrent?

Tags: cuda, thread-safety

When using only driver API and multiple CPU threads for only a single context(to feed a single GPU for both data copy and multiple kernel executions):

Is cuCtxSetCurrent(sameCtx) thread-safe when other threads:

- Also have cuCtxSetCurrent(sameCtx)?
- Have blocking cu__() functions that use sameCtx?
- Have callbacks that were already prepared by sameCtx?

Comment: multiple CPU threads can share the same context.  This is the default behavior for the CUDA runtime API.  There aren't any differences with the driver API AFAIK.  There shouldn't be any restrictions around multiple threads doing `cuCtxSetCurrent(sameCtx)`.

Comment: Do you mean that if I have a parallel_for implementation having each thread starting with simply a cuCtxSetCurrent, then finally all those threads joining main thread, will not be an issue? Thank you.

Comment: It should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple CPU threads can share the same context. This is the default behavior for the CUDA runtime API.  It's also true for the driver API.

There shouldn't be any restrictions around multiple threads doing `cuCtxSetCurrent(sameCtx)`.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Maybe I should delete the comment of my own.